# How to install node-xmpp on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, node-xmpp

How to install [node-xmpp](https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp) on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Dependencies node.js

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

### Install node.js & npm the correct way

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

### Install node-xmpp dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat1 libexpat1-dev 
npm install node-expat
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev 
npm install node-stringprep
```

### install node-xmpp

```
npm install node-xmpp
```